# rsync maintain folder structure given point

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to develop a file updater for my remote server. So each time I modify some code files on my workstation, I would run `rsync` and it would modify the code files on the remote server.

So imagine if I modify the file `/home/myuser/workspaces/project/folder/file.txt` I would want to sync it to `user@remote.server:/work/folder/file.txt`. As you can see, the server maintains the folder structure, although it skips the irrelevant part `/home/myuser/workspaces/project/`

If I execute the rsync from `/home/myuser/workspaces/project/` it's easy to solve, since I just have to add the `-R` option:

```
$ cd /home/myuser/workspaces/project/
$ rsync -aR folder/file.txt user@remote.server:/work
```

This would do the trick. The problem is that I don't know where the command will be executed from, so I have to add the whole path `/home/.../file.txt`, and using the shown command would save everything into: `user@remote.server:/work/home/myuser/workspaces/project/folder/file.txt`.

Is there any solution to what I want to implement?

By the way, at the moment of the `rsync`, it could be possible that `/work/`, at the remote host, is an empty folder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just for the future, I found the quickest solution which involves the `-R` parameter and adding a `/./` before the folder you want to start creating from.

For example:

```
 $ rsync -aR /home/myuser/workspaces/project/./folder/file.txt user@remote.server:/work
```

will create the folder `/work/folder/file.txt` in the remote server.

Just leaving this answer for future use and for other people to see, since it was really hard to find it on other websites.